# The sorted file is not saved correctly

Tags: sort

If I sort a file, I want save it in the new one. I use for this just:

```
sort -nk{fieldnumber} test.json > testsort.json
```

In the output the columns are shuffled and the column, which I have sorted, is in random order (not ascending). Why is it happen?
Also, I want split this sorted file in many parts. I wish all parts are also sorted by the column, like here:

```
partaa
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':1}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':1}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':2}

partab
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':2}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':3}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':3}

partac
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':4}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':5}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':6}
```

I use for it

```
split -l 100 testsort.json part
```

Anyway, I have the all time the shuffled, unordered output. (for example some value from partac could be lesser then from partab)

**PS**

Thank you, I have found the problem someself. The input was corrupt, because some lines have additional fields.

```
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':2}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':1}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':2}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'd':'d', 'c':1}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':3}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'f':'f', 'c':4}
```

I construct next regular expression, which search for certain field, take the numeric values, bring them in the front and sort them

```
sed -e 's/^\(.*columnname\)\([^,]*\)/\2\t\1\2/;s/^[" :]*//' test.json | sort -nk1 |sed -e 's/^[^{]*//' > testSort.json
```

Comment: You say the command worked? Now **I** have a question ;) See my answer.

Comment: If the solution, and how you found it, can be of use for other readers, write an answer please! (If it does not help to understand the question really, let's just wait for it to get closed)

Comment: Ah, I see, the extra columns like `'f':'f',` makes itcomplicated with `sort` alone; It is not made for this kind of data. So `sed` is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The field separator of sort is not specified in your command:

```
sort -nk25
```

By default, the **field separator** of sort consists of whitespace<sup>1</sup>.
That means you sort on the 25th field of 3 fields.
It's not really clear on what you want to sort - but you could try to sort on whitespace separated column 3 with:

```
sort -nk3
```

Depending on what exactly you see as columns, you may run into the problem that the field separator can only be a single character, not a set of characters, (or even a regular expression) - except for the special case described below.
So you can use the quote as field separator, like `sort -t"'" ...`, and sort on the character values; It does not work like this with the numbers, because they are not quoted.

---

(1): The default field separator does not consist off a single or fixed count of space characters. The separator is a non-blank to blank transition - that makes any string of whitespace that does not start in the first column a separator.

Comment: thank you, but the main problem is, a file is corrupt.... Some lines have additional fields and it doesn't make a sense sort by some field (column), because all values are shifted.. I already construct some solution with regular expression.

Comment: Good! If you can add that shifted input to the question, I'd be curious whether it can be solved by sort to; The sort key definitions of sort are so powerfull that the description is outright scary ;)

Comment: I'm very sorry, it was unclear. -nk25 came from the real programm, of course not correlated with the toy example here. Sorry, I have supposed, it would be clear...

Comment: Looks like `sort -nk3` does not work either, because numeric sort does not ignore the non-digits.

Comment: I suppose -nk9 will sort the table without additional fields.

Comment: Why `-k9`? The table has only three columns, separated by space characters?

Comment: use `awk '{print $n}' test.json` for undestanding of the fields. Short to say., is not a dictionary, is some string, and some field has three different values (`key`, `:`, `value`). You understand it like only one.

Comment: I do understand the json data structure. The point is that for `sort`, the text `'k':'v',` is only one field, because the field separator is whitespace, and there is no whitespace in it. And note I wrote "text" there; Foe `sort`, it's just 8 non-whitespace characters - as long as you do not write a key specification explaining it.

Comment: It depends from the input, where you have whitespace

Comment: So you use a different kind of input?

Comment: I can execute both commands, without and with blanks and get sort output in both cases. I really don't know, why you have problem with `-nk3`, I just expected, you have additional blanks.

Comment: Maybe we have different versions of `sort`? (GNU for me). But from what you say - maybe the output is just sorted by chance? If you want to still spend time on it, I'd be curious to find out what we see different. If you give a complete example with input, command, and output, that may help. Make sure to preserve whitespace, of course ;)  (by the way, try the `--debug` option of sort)

Comment: ok, this is interesting. General, I'm agree with you, but anyway I have some sorted output from the random input...  My data: `{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':12}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':1}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':12}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':21}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':33}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':35}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':14}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':15}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':64}`

Comment: Output is `{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':1}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':12}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':12}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':14}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':15}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':21}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':33}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':35}
{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':64}`

Comment: Ok, just for confirmation, the input ans output is from the command `sort -nk3`, right? And both files have 9 lines? And the lines have no whitespace after the rightmost `}`? And the first line of the input, with all (two) space characters replaced by `_` is this: `{'a':'a',_'b':'b',_'c':12}`? If you confirm, we have a well defined base :)

Comment: Yes, it's right for all points